# Chain of promises

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6

Often I end up with

```
var askName = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.waitForInput('Name:').then(name => {
            this.ask('Are there more players?', ['Yes', 'No']).then(answer => {
                if(answer === 'yes') {
                    askName().then(resolve);
                } else {
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
askName();
```

when I need to chain promises. Now, in ES7 it will be possible to write this as

```
var morePlayers = true;
while(moreUsers){
    var name = await this.waitForInput('Name:');
    var morePlayers = (await this.ask('Are there more players?', ['Yes', 'No'])) === 'yes';
}
```

which is of course beautiful, but how can this be written as neatly as possible supporting the most recent versions of Chrome and Firefox (and probably Edge as well)?

Comment: @Quill Thanks, it's the weirdest typo I always end up making... I have no idea why

Comment: And @the 2 downvoters, it would be absolutely great if you guys would explain your reasoning ;-) .

Comment: You probably mean ES7 rather than ES6. OTH, the reason for the downvotes (not me) is probably that this does not quite seem relevant for codereview.SE. Stackoverflow maybe?

Comment: @jcaron You were right about ES7 (which also explains why browsers don't implement it yet :( ), and this would be off-topic as opinion-based on SO as I am asking about 'best practices and design pattern usage'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use generators to bring the code down to a form that's almost as small and readable as if using `async`.

```
doAsync(function* () {
  var morePlayers = true;
  while (moreUsers) { // assuming morePlayers
    var name = yield this.waitForInput('Name:');
    var morePlayers = (yield this.ask('Are there more players?', ['Yes', 'No'])) === 'yes';
  }
})
```

Why does this work? Every time the generator function yields it gives control back to the `doAsync` function. This function unwraps waits until the promise resolved, gets its result and plugs it back in the generator through the same yield it ceased control earlier.

Comment: This might be an incredibly stupid question, but how is `doAsync` defined here? I have quite little experience with generators, but I haven't seen anybody use a return value for `yield` before, so I am a bit confused.

Comment: @DavidMulder generators have a `next` method which can optionally take a parameter - this optional parameter becomes the result of the yield expression. Generators also have a `throw` method which you can use in the same way to pass on the reason of a rejected promise.